# How to count vowels, consonants, digits in a txt file using redirection in C

Tags: c

Brand new C coder here. In my first C course in school. I have experience in java but this course is all in C. I have homework to create a program that reads the contents of a file and counts the number of upper and lower case letters, vowels, consonants and digits. The program is not supposed to have any arguments, but will take a .txt file from the command line via redirection. My question is, how do I correct my current code to read from stdin each character of the file, whether it be a letter or a number? I'm really struggling with how read the contents of the file from stdin, read each character and then decide which category it belongs in. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I'll be running the program like this...

$ program < testFile.txt

Where testFile.txt will contain the following text:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789

```
int upper = 0;  // Number of upper case letters
int lower = 0;  // Number of lower case letters
int vowel = 0;  // Number of vowels
int consonant = 0;  // Number of constants
int digits = 0; // Number of digits
int total = 0;  // Total number of characters in file
int i =0;

char value[100];

fgets(value, 100, stdin);

while(value[i] != '\0');
{


    if (value[i] >= 'A' && value[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        upper++;

        if (value[i] == 'A' || value[i] == 'E' || value[i] == 'I' || value[i] == 'O' || value[i] == 'U' || value[i] == 'Y')
        {
            vowel++;

        }
        else {

            consonant++;

        }
    }

    else if (value[i] >= 'a' && value[i] <= 'z')
    {
        lower++;

        if (value[i] == 'a' || value[i] == 'e' || value[i] ==      'i' || value[i] == 'o' || value[i] == 'u' || value[i] == 'y')
        {
            vowel++;

        }
        else {

            consonant++;
        }

    }

    else if (value[i] >= '0' && value[i] <= '9')
    {
        digits++;

    }

    total++;
    i++;

}

printf("upper-case: %d", upper);
printf("\nlower-case: %d", lower);
printf("\nvowels: %d", vowel);
printf("\nconsonants: %d", consonant);
printf("\ndigits: %d", digits);
printf("\ntotal: %d", total);
printf("\n");

return 0;
```

I expect output to show how many upper case letters, lower case letters etc.
But once I run $ program < testFile.txt, it just sits there, no output to command line or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(value[i] != '\0');
```

This is your most *obvious* problem, it basically means:

```
while value[i] != '\0':
    do nothing
end while
```

In other words, if it *enters* the loop, it will *never* exit it, because nothing changes that would affect the condition under which the loop continues.

---

There are *other* problems as well such as the fact that you will only process the first line rather than the whole file. The whole idea of using `fgets` and processing a line is unnecessary when you can just start with the following filter skeleton:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    /* process ch */
}
```

This will process an entire file character by character until all characters are done (or until an error occurs) so you can just tailor the body loop to do what you need - you've basically done that bit in your code with the loop over the line characters.

I would suggest *not* using the following code (since this is classwork) but you can also make better use of flow control constructs and library functions (from `ctype.h` and `string.h`), something like:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    // Lib functions to detect upper/lower-case letters.

    if (isupper(ch)) {
        ++upper;
    } else if (islower(ch))
        ++lower;
    }

    // And to detect letter/digit type.

    if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", ch) != NULL) {
        ++vowel;
    } else if (isalpha(ch)) {
        ++consonant;
    } else if (isdigit(ch)) {
        ++digits;
    }

    ++total;
}
```

This is *particularly* important since there's no actual guarantee that non-digit characters will be consecutive.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help! Can't believe I didnt catch the semicolon. Also thanks for the detailed explanation pax, I'll take a another crack at my program and see how I do.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semicolon after the while statement. :-)

Comment: These are the kinds of mistakes that can sometimes take days to find.  Everything looks fine until you see that...  Nice catch.

Comment: I didn't notice it at first. I thought, looks good to me, let me run it locally and see if it works. But gcc immediately gave me a warning, "while loop has empty body."

Comment: @CDav117 I'm wondering what compiler you're using and why it didn't give you a warning? The pattern of an empty while followed by a random block is pretty suspicious.